# deleting few array values

Tags: php, arrays

i need help in creating skip rules

i have array of 15rows,need to skip few rows from the array.(skip values is provide by the user)

im facing issues in array skip, 
if user provides 1 skip  only 1 row need to deleted but below function 2 rows are getting deleted

CASES : user1 wants to  skip 2 rows,user2 wants to skip 1 row from given 15 rows
2 skip deleting 3 rows, 1 skip deletes 2 rows

```
function array_delete($idx, $array) {
                for ($i = 0; $i <= $idx; $i++) {
                    unset($array[$i]);
                }
                return (is_array($array)) ? array_values($array) : null;
            }
$numberSkip = 1;
$skipnumber = $skipnumber - $numberSkip;
$Arrayvalue = array_delete($skipnumber, $Array);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "skipping rows"?

Comment: I'm a bit fuzzy on exactly how you want this to work, but one nitpicky piece of advice: pick a naming convention for variables and function names and stick with it.

Comment: @Jeffrey "skipping rows" need to delete few records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $idx; $i++)
```

into

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $idx; $i++)
```

Using `<=` makes your loop run exactly one time too much: if `$idx = 1` then the loop will run for `$i = 0` and `$i = 1`. Changing `<=` into `<` will solve this problem and will have your loop run the desired amount of times.